# Do muffled garments guarantee complete silence?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm discarding most of the Dark Brotherhood armor, but I like the shoes, which have a "muffled" enchantment. I've got elven boots that have 30% sneaking buff - but it's worth sacrificing armor points if I can make no noise while sneaking... exactly *what* does the *muffle enchantment do*?

Extra question: Can I learn this enchantment? It doesn't seem to be possible...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to learn the muffle enchantment.  Note that you can only put it on footwear though.

The reason why you can't get it off of the dark brotherhood armor is because you are not allowed to disenchant it.  If you find a pair of random boots with the muffle enchantment on it, you can disenchant it to learn the effect.

Your enchantment has a hidden magnitude effect that lowers your armor weight penalty by a % (from 0-1).  A magnitude of 1 will mean you suffer no noise penalty to armor at all.

Note, you can reproduce this effect with the muffle illusion spell and/or the silence perk.

Comment: thank you for answering, but I admit I am slightly confused with the third paragraph. can you please dumb it down for me? are my elven boots with 30% sneak better or muffled boots? how do I find out? thanks again :)

Comment: @desaiw does your spell give you away when you cast it?  its because you don't have the silent cast perk

Comment: @adityamenon its something that can only be seen via modding or when the CES comes out.  Even though you can't tell whats the magnitude of the muffle enchantment when you enchant it, it does have a hidden magnitude value that varies between 1-100%

Comment: aah - so it looks like I'm going to stick with % sneaking buffs because I know how silent I will be, compared to wearing muffled gear and hoping for the best :) thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, muffled garments do guarantee complete silence. By the way, the only thing you can muffle is boots — only those you find though, not DB boots or TG boots.