# Muffle Magnitude Difference

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've discovered that the Muffle effect might have different magnitudes. Seems like those found on Nightingale Boots, shrouded boots and so on only have a magnitude of 0.5.

Whats the magnitude of the Muffle spell?

I have to know it so I can decide when to use enchanted boots or the spell itself.

Also, is it true that any item enchanted with Muffle effect will have a magnitude of 1.0?

Comment: its currently unknown exactly what the muffle magnitude does, but since the CS is out it'll be figured out soon enough.

Comment: Whats CS ? Enlight me so i may help to figure it out

Comment: Could the person who down voted the OPs question explain why? It seems like a perfectly valid question to me, so I don't understand why it was down voted.

Comment: @Marcello I meant the Skyrim Creation Kit

Comment: OPs Question? You meant mine ? Someone voted my question down ?

Comment: @Wipqozn Agreed! Side Note: I hate drive by down votes!

Comment: @Marcello For your second question, asking about enchanting items with the muffle effect. Are you asking if their magnitude equals 1.0,   or if their magnitude can not exceed 1.0?

Comment: @marcello Yeah, OP stands for "Original Poster". Someone down voted your question, and I'm uncertain why. We encourage users to leave a comment when down voting so that the OP knows how to improve their question. When down votes are left without comments and the reasons for doing so are unclear, you'll often see users (like myself) wanting to know the reason why.

Comment: It's still possible that Muffle has magnitude but it doesn't do anything, like Cure Disease. Also, the last level of [Nightingale Boots](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Nightingale_Boots#Nightingale_Boots) (level 32+) has a Muffle effect of **35.0**. If there's any difference to notice, it should be there.

Comment: You meant `0.35` or `35.0` ? Muffle spells helps, at least when i tested it helped me not to make noise, but i can't measure how it helped. So you are saying that level 32+ Nightingale Boots have the greatest `Muffle Magnitude` in the game ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay, so scratch what I said above in the comments. Apparently folks *have* figured out how [Muffle](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Muffle_%28effect%29) works.

**Spells**
[Muffle](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Muffle) - 1.0

**Perks**
[Muffled Movement](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Sneak#Skill_Perks) - 0.5
[Silence](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Sneak#Skill_Perks) - 1.0

**Apparel**
[Nightingale Boots](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Nightingale_Boots#Nightingale_Boots) - 35.0 (level 32+ only)
[Predator's Grace](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Predator%27s_Grace#Predator.27s_Grace) - 1.0
Everything else - 0.5

**Enchanting**
Apparently, any item *enchanted by the player* with the [Muffle effect](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Muffle) will have 1.0. This number is not affected by your enchanting level or gem size used on the enchanting process.

Noise from armor is then multiplied by `1 - sum of muffle effects`, so if you have two items of 0.5 or one item of 1.0, your armor will make no noise. Any increase above 1.0, including via the best Nightingale Boots, has no additional effect. And yes, it will cut in half or completely eliminate noise from [heavy armor](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Heavy_Armor#Notes) just as well as light armor:

> However, heavy armor is also noisier to move in than light armor, so it always adds a penalty to stealth. The Silence perk of the Sneak skill eliminates this drawback, as does the Muffle spell/enchantment.

**See also:**
[Can you sneak well with heavy armor compared to light or is there no difference?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36079/can-you-sneak-well-with-heavy-armor-compared-to-light-or-is-there-no-difference)
[How does Silence work in the Sneak tree?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36254/how-does-silence-work-in-the-sneak-tree/36261#36261)
[Do muffled garments guarantee complete silence?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/46970/14402)

Comment: Not trying to doubt you, but, any source ?

Comment: This `Total silence Effect` Also aplies to Heavy Armor sneaking ? Can i use Nightingale Boots with full daedric set and still have the full silence from armor ?

Comment: Answer me, can i be as "stealthy" as i would be using light armor, when using Heavy armor with Muffle + sneaking "silence" perk ?

Comment: @MarcelloGrechiLins I think this post is pretty well-linked. If you have any questions about Muffle's effect, I would [go here](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Muffle_(effect)). Anyway, yes, Muffle can reduce the noise from all armor completely, no exceptions.

Comment: Last question, in your link it is written that : Muffle 1.0 may be achieved picking the perk "silence". So, i would not need muffle spells or effects if i have the "silence" perk ?

Comment: [Yes.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/36261/14402) Keep in mind, though, that unless you plan on taking the Shadow Warrior perk, that's arguably a waste as it's so easy to just enchant a pair of boots that will provide the same effect (no matter what your enchanting level). Keep in mind, though, that enemies are still just as likely to detect you through line of sight, and that's much harder to deal with than sneaking up on someone from behind.

Comment: I do plan to take the Shadow Warrior Perk. I will have no Muffle in my gear so,since i have Silence. Thanks :D